# How to fetch an number from a varchar column and check the value is within range

Tags: sql-server

Below is my table, I want to fetch the numbers inside the bracket and count the number of records within 90 to 95

```
Id  title
----------------
1   Text1 (85)
2   test2(95)
3   text3 (95)
4   text4 (85)
5   text5(94)
6   Text6, The (83)
7   Text: 7 (95)
8   text8 (text) (85)
```

My query:

```
select 
    title, 
    (substring(title, patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1, len(title) - case patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) 
when 0 then 0 else patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1 end))
```

This query is listing the numeric values. But I am not sure how to check the range and take the record count.

Comment: `sum(case when     (substring(title, patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1, len(title) - case patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) 
when 0 then 0 else patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1 end))*1 between 90 and 95 then 1 else 0 end) as between95and100`

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your dilemma could be solved by putting the regex query in a subquery and then counting with a WHERE clause

```
if object_id('TempDb..#Temp') is not null drop table #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        id int,
        title varchar(50)
    );

INSERT INTO #Temp (id, title) VALUES
(1, 'Text1 (85)'),
(2, 'test2(95)'),
(3, 'text3 (95)'),
(4, ' text4 (85)'),
(5, 'text5(94)'),
(6, 'Text6, The (83)'),
(7, 'Text: 7 (95)'),
(8, 'text8 (text) (85)');

SELECT 
    COUNT(Number) AS CountofRange
FROM
    (
        select 
            (substring(title, patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1, len(title) - case patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) 
            when 0 then 0 else patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1 end)) AS Number
        FROM #Temp
    ) z
WHERE 
    Number BETWEEN 90 and 95
```

And another version without the correlated subquery:

```
if object_id('TempDb..#Temp') is not null drop table #Temp;

CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        id int,
        title varchar(50)
    );

INSERT INTO #Temp (id, title) VALUES
(1, 'Text1 (85)'),
(2, 'test2(95)'),
(3, 'text3 (95)'),
(4, ' text4 (85)'),
(5, 'text5(94)'),
(6, 'Text6, The (83)'),
(7, 'Text: 7 (95)'),
(8, 'text8 (text) (85)');

select 
    SUM
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN 
                (substring(title, patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1, len(title) - case patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) 
                when 0 then 0 else patindex('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1 end)) BETWEEN 90 and 95 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
                END
        )
    AS Number
FROM #Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Just put what you have in sub-query and count the rows with the desired value.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
(
    ID INT
  , title VARCHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO #Table
(
    ID
  , title
)
VALUES
(1, 'Text1 (85)')
, (2, 'test2(95)')
, (3, 'text3 (95)')
, (4, 'text4 (85)')
, (5, 'text5(94)')
, (6, 'Text6, The (83)')
, (7, 'Text: 7 (95)')
, (8, 'text8 (text) (85)');

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
           SELECT title
                , (SUBSTRING(
                                title
                              , PATINDEX('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1
                              , LEN(title) - CASE PATINDEX('%([0-9]%)', title)
                                                 WHEN 0 THEN
                                                     0
                                                 ELSE
                                                     PATINDEX('%([0-9]%)', title) + 1
                                             END
                            )
                  ) AS EmbeddedNumber
           FROM   #Table
       ) AS X
WHERE  X.EmbeddedNumber BETWEEN 90 AND 95;
```

Comment: beat you to it :P

Comment: Thanks @DougCoats i am getting error if one of the value is 1-900 (06) (94) "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '06) (94' to data type int."

Comment: Thanks @Isaac . .

Comment: @User1882624 Thats because you have two sets of parenthesis. You may need to rework you regex